# Do I really need Flink checkpointing?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink Application that reads some events from Kafka, does some enrichment of the data from MySQL, buffers the data using a window function and writes the data inside a window to HBase. I've currently enabled checkpointing, but it turns out that the checkpointing is quite expensive and over time it takes longer and longer and affects my job's latency (falling behind on kafka ingest rate). If I figure out a way to make my HBase writes idempotent, is there a strong reason for me to use checkpointing? I can just configure the internal kafka consumer client to commit every so often right?

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you are checkpointing is the Kafka provider offset(s), then it would surprise me that the checkpointing time is significant enough to slow down your workflow. Or is state being saved elsewhere as well? If so, you could skip that (as long as, per your note, the HBase writes are idempotent).

Note that you can also adjust the checkpointing interval, and (if need be) use incremental checkpoints with RocksDB.

Comment: I adjusted my application's checkpoint interval. Turns out 15sec was too frequent. I also adjusted setMinPauseBetweenCheckpoints to ensure the app was making progress.